# Control the close button in PayPal Express Checkout

Tags: ios, paypal, webview

I red here about Express Checkout:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECOnMobileDevices/

When you redirect to PayPal and the buyer pays on PayPal, the following Login page appears on an iOS device:

[image]

As you can see, in the top right corner, there's a close button ("x"). Is there any way to control that button? That is: I load this page in a native app webview and, when I click it, I want to close this view.

I don't want to use the native SDK, only a webview.